# htaccess url rewrite wont allow other pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a script thanks to Howlin that will rewrite my url, however, I cannot access any other page then, it just gives a 404 error?

The rewrite rewrites `localhost/docci.me/profile.php?user=person` to `localhost/docci.me/person` and it works, but as soon as I try to load `logout.php`, `index.php`, or any other page, it gives a 404. If I take the .htaccess code out, it works fine but obviously does not rewrite the URL like I need it to.

here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /docci.me/login/profile\.php\?user=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /docci.me/login/%2\? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /docci.me/login/profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is `/docci.me/` in your rules?

Comment: it is the project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in `/docci.me/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /docci.me/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /login/profile\.php\?user=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ login/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ login/profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This seems to work if I type in a manual URL, but I cannot redirect using it. If I log in, it stays on the login page (but it is logged in)

Comment: see updated answer and tell me for which full URL it doesn't work.

Comment: I can make `anchorlinks` to other pages, but it will not redirect to the profile page itself

Comment: Try answering directly to get better help. What is the URL that didn't work for you? Is it causing 404 or wrong redirect? Are there more rules in this .htaccess?